# Why does numpy give correct least squares solution but not scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, least-squares

I am scratching my head over this very simple problem. Given this toy data:

```
randgen = np.random.RandomState(9)
npoints = 1000
noise = randgen.randn(npoints)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, npoints)
y = 5 + 10*x + noise
```

Solving this using numpy's least squares:

```
# design matrix::
X = np.ones((npoints, 2))
X[:,0] = np.copy(x)  
p, res, rnk, s = np.linalg.lstsq(X, y)
p
```

gives a reasonable answer: `array([ 9.94406755,  5.05954009])` for `p`. However, solving using scipy's least squares gives wildly different answer (which changes on each invocation of the function):

```
p, res, rnk, s = scipy.linalg.lstsq(X, y)
p
```

An example solution is `array([  1.16328381e+08,  -2.26560583e+06])`. I don't understand what I am missing. I encountered this problem when using Scikit-learn's `LinearRegression` which internally uses scipy's `lstsq`. That was giving me weird answers.

**Edit:**
Numpy version: 1.11.2
Scipy version: 0.18.1
Python: 3.5

**Edit 2:**
I have realized that loading a particular library before loading scipy is causing this problem. The following order of loading libraries causes problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma import MaskedArray
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pyeemd import ceemdan
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from sklearn.utils.extmath import svd_flip
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from scipy.signal import convolve, boxcar
```

If I removed the `from pyeemd import ceemdan` line then the problem is solved! This raises the following question: why could this be happening?

Comment: try `np.linalg.lstsq(X, y, rcond=None)` - it gives me the same `p` value... `np.__version__ =  '1.14.0'`, `scipy.__version__ = '1.0.0'`

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/fARQhY)

Comment: What SciPy version are you on?

Comment: I added the versions.

Comment: Ideone is on the same SciPy version you're on, and NumPy 1.12.0. Are you sure you didn't accidentally alter `X` or `y`? If not, maybe you have a bad LAPACK.

Comment: Hmm looks like loading a particular library before loading scipy is causing this problem. This is so unbelievably weird. I updated the question with the particulars of this problem.

Comment: Maybe a library shared object conflict? Does it still work if you do the `pyeemd` import last?